# Unable to install elementary OS: Hardware errors

Tags: system-installation

While installing elementary OS from USB, my computer shows a black screen. [image: Screenshot of black screen]

Could you please help me what's wrong?

Comment: It's a hardware error. "Machine Check Error" always reports problem with the hardware. It can be either CPU or RAM. if you have several modules of RAM try re-arranging them. E.g. launch installation only with 1st RAM module, if it fails - try with second. Try all them 1 by 1. If all fail - it ought to be a CPU, or, maybe, a motherboard.

Comment: At this point is appears you have a hardware problem, which is out of scope for the site, and therefore the question will have to be closed. However, I have a question regarding the system: **Do you run a current OS on the system?**

Answer (score 4):

[Machine-check exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception) are hardware-related, that's not an OS problem. Your hardware is physically broken.